# NEST Query datetime range of jdbc river datetime format in Elasticsearch .net c#

Tags: datetime, jdbc, elasticsearch, range, nest

I try to using NEST to query between specific datetime on Elasticsearch such as

```
    string DateFrom="20100815";
    string DateTo="20100815";
    string pattern = "yyyyMMdd";
    string CustomerID ="12345";
    string PONO ="xxx";
    string SONO ="xxx";
    DateTime.TryParseExact(DateFrom, pattern, null,DateTimeStyles.None, out dtf);
    DateTime.TryParseExact(DateTo, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtt);
    var result = ElasticClient.Search<TrackTraceObj>(s => s
                .Index("index")
                .Type("xxx")
                .Query(q => q.Term("CusCode", CustomerID) && q.Term("PO_NO", PONO) && q.Term("Sales_Order", SONO) 
                 && q.Range(n => n
                .OnField(f => f.CreateDate)
                .From(dtf)
                .To(dtt)
                .FromExclusive()
            ))
     );
```

but my results always return nothing when i add range into this query string.
note: dateformat in my Elasticsearch that keep from jdbc-river is look like

```
    CreateDate: "2014-06-18T12:16:10.910Z"
```

Comment: Now I found the solution of this problem.

I change my function 
        .From(dtf)
        .To(dtt)

to the FilterRaw with string input 

It's may be the bug of ES datetime range query